# Monitor Skydrive Shared File Downloads

Tags: download, monitoring, onedrive

I use SkyDrive to share some large non-email-able files to family and clients. Since I only have so much space on SkyDrive, I like to delete these files after sharing. It seems like every time I delete a file though, I get an email from someone who wants to access it. It gets a little annoying, because I leave the files available for a long time.

Is there anyway to track when a user downloads a shared file from SkyDrive?

Comment: I just Googled this very question and came across a couple of Microsoft support-group posts from early 2013 that say it isn't possible at the moment. One post suggested that those wanting such a function in SkyDrive should send a feature request to Microsoft. This would be very handy for me and I suspect for many others, so I hope many people will do so.